# Can't reach maven profile property 'spring.profiles.active' from application.properties file after upgrade spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: spring, maven, properties, profile, spring-boot-starter-parent

I upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.3.1 till 2.5.5 and now 'spring.profiles.active' property can't be injected from pom to application.properties file. Instead of profile value I get in console *"The following profiles are active @spring.active.profile@"*

My .pom file

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

application.properties

```
spring.profile.active=@spring.profile.active@
```

Comment: Why do you need Maven profiles? In Spring Boot you can create different application.properties files. First `application.properties` which will be used if no spring profile is defined. `application-dev.properties` if you use `--spring.profiles.active=dev` etc. So usually it's a bad idea to use maven profiles...better use spring profiles...I strongly recommend to read about spring profiles: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles

Comment: Please provide the entire pom.xml. Where are you setting up the filtering of the application.properties file? Ideally we'd need a runnable example - create a smaller project in Github or something. If you can reproduce the same bug in that, we might be able to help you.